# Golang GORP - No error, no results

Tags: mysql, go, gorp

```
dbCount, er2 = dbmap.SelectInt("SELECT COUNT(*) AS N FROM (SELECT av.id FROM Table av LEFT JOIN Table2 dt ON dt.`app_id` = av.`app_id` LEFT JOIN Table3 a ON a.`id` = av.`app_id` WHERE dt.`user_id` IN (?) OR a.`org_id` IN (?) GROUP BY av.id LIMIT ? OFFSET ?) tmp", user_id, org_ids, limit, offset)
```

`user_id = 1000`
`org_ids = 13444,12444,10333`
`limit = 25`
`offset = 0`

Any idea why this returns no error or results in GO but when run directly on the database returns 1 result? There are no errors either.

Comment: Why do you have a nested query? How about `select count(1) from Table ... joins ect`. Not that it's going to solve your problem, but it could be related.

Comment: Because of the GROUP BY. COUNT does not respect the GROUP BY so you have to do a sub select.